# Trouble with deploying Django app with Git submodule

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, git-submodules, pythonpath

I'll try to skinny this question as best as I can so that it's not too vague.

So I'm using this [django-ajax-validation](https://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation) plugin in a Django app. I'm fairly certain that the problem I'm running into lies somewhere between my settings.py and Heroku. When I deploy I get this error message:

> 2013-03-08T18:54:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py    runserver 0.0.0.0:53994 --noreload`
>   2013-03-08T18:54:18+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: No module named ajax_validation
>   2013-03-08T18:54:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>   2013-03-08T18:54:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

In my installed apps I have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'ajax_validation',
```

among other things.

In the django-ajax-validation docs the author mentions adding `ajax_validation/` to your `PYTHONPATH` and `ajax_validation` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in order to install the plugin. Maybe because I'm inexperienced, I found the former step vague and the closest thing I could find was installing his `setup.py` file with `python setup.py install`

Is this incorrect? Is there a different way to add the app as a module?

Let me know if I need to clear anything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news for you, Heroku supports python packages installation via pip, which is a very usefull tool to manage django apps. Everything is explained on Heroku’s website: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip.

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks for the reference, I ran a couple pip installs and added the submodule in my requirements.txt and Heroku was finally able to install the package. You saved me much more wasted time.